# How do I center a div in the middle of the page using jQuery and keep it centered when window is re-sized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, positioning

Does anyone know of any jQuery Script that will keep a div centered in the middle and when the window is re-sized, it will also keep it centered? I am building a lightbox plugin and I need it to stay in the middle. I tried using CSS but it doesn't work.

Also I need it to stay in the middle when another box is opened that has a bigger width and height. Here's the page with examples on it:

http://wowbox.yolasite.com/

Open the image first, and then open the div, and you'll see what I mean. The div is not centered. But then when you close and re-open the div it is centered because of the .center() that happens when you click on a WowBox link. I just need it to always be centered, and never mess up like that.

Here is the code I'm currently using to center it:

```
  jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
  }
```

I want to make it where when the window re-sizes, it will stay centered. I also want to make it where when the width of the box gets wider and the height gets taller, it will re-center. Right now it doesn't work right.

Could anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance,

Nathan

Comment: try $(this).height() instead of this.outerHeight()

Comment: my css solution works, unless I'm understanding what you want incorrectly

Comment: @Kamil Szot I tried that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that along with the example code you already have. For clarification:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.element').center();
   window.onresize = function(event) {
        $('.element').center();
    }
});
```

Comment: The function he has above is written as a plugin! So why the downvote? The usage of his example code is .center();

Comment: is there something I'm not getting? why not use just css?

Comment: Your CSS solution does look good actually. Does this work cross browser? I went for the jQuery option as the question was titled "How do I center a div in the middle of the page using **jQuery** and keep it centered when window is re-sized?"

Comment: @kieran Thanks for the answer. That looks like it should work. I'm going to try it right now.

Answer (score 1):

-----------------[This](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/m4Ttk/5/) works---------------------

CSS

```
       .box{
    width:200px;
    top:-5px; 

    position:relative;
    background:#444;
}
.inner {
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    background:#444;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    right:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    position:relative;
}
```

.outer {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    border:2px dotted red;
}

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
    <div class="box">
        wpfw efuiweh fuiwehf weuifh weuifh fuihwe fuihwefuiweh uwehf iuwehf uiwefhweuifh weuifhwe fuiweh fuiwehfuiwefh uiwefh weuifh weuifh weuifhwe uifh weuifhwefuiweh fuiweh fuiwehf iweufh weuih
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $(".box").css('top',-($(".box").height()/2));
    $(".box").css('left',-($(".box").width()/2));
});
```

---

Please let me know if that doesn't do what you want it to.
You can even see on http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/m4Ttk/2/ that resizing the inner our outer divs will still keep it centered.

Comment: Please let me know what's wrong with that? Doesn't it center and make it in the middle?

Comment: The solution you provided is not working, it does not center vertically.

Comment: The first one is working, the second not. But i like the CSS approach

Comment: The second one will work only if the .box height is constant. The question was: "...I also want to make it where when the width of the box gets wider and the height gets taller, it will re-center..."

Comment: then just add `$(function(){
    $(".box").css('top',-($(".box").height()/2));
    $(".box").css('left',-($(".box").width()/2));
});` ... pretty simple? I think CSS and minimal jquery is better than all jQuery

Comment: @mazlix Thanks for the answer. But what's wrong with using all jQuery?

Comment: Jumping.. using only jQuery nothing is moved until the DOM is finished loading. so it goes from default position to the middle... If for whatever reason the browser is slow at processing javascript (maybe someone has many tabs open/slow computer) then the div will start in the default spot and then move to the middle. Using css, not only are you closer to the middle for javascript disabled browsers, but also there would be a smaller jump... Also it's less javascript so I imagine it would run faster...

Comment: @mazlix This is a lightbox plugin though, meaning people without JavaScript are out of luck. (They really need to enable it though. It is dumb to have JavaScript disabled these days.) Also, the box wont be popped up until after the page has loaded anyways, so I think by then the jQuery would have been loaded. 

Your CSS solution looks like it will work. But, how will I make it work with my lightbox? Because you have #outer and #inner divs. Will I have to have those divs on my lightbox too?  

Thanks again, mazlix, for providing a different way to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

for fixed-size fits example http://jsfiddle.net/expert/vh2vy/5/