# jquery center a div in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, center

I am working on a [Lightbox (tutorial)](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html), a div container which opens on a click. 
This div container isn´t displayed and is located under the click element.
Now i tried to center it vertical but withouth success.
Found some other questions here on Stackoverflow, but no one worked for me, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787237/how-do-i-center-a-div-in-the-middle-of-the-page-using-jquery-and-keep-it-centere).

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".modal-box").css({
    top: (($(window).height()  - $(".modal-box").outerHeight() / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px")
  });
});
```

The problem is: At the beginning the div is almost out of the bottem screen and divs below gone out of top screen.
I would have each div in the middle of the screen, no matter of the position.

Comment: plz create a jsfiddle

Comment: This can be done with CSS alone. You want that solution?

Comment: I tried already with css, withouth no success =). If you have a solution i would be happy with it =).

Comment: create a jsfiddle or post your html with some css

Comment: what browsers you need to support, or what version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: Ok there you go [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usjpLjLp/). It seems it isn´t working just on my page. Better would be link my page... On Fiddle doesn´t displayed well my problem... But won´t share my page sorry.

Comment: @AlexNikulin all browser and ~ie8-ie9.

Comment: i don't think manually setting `top` on window resize is helping you any. Remove that and add a % top in the css like [this update](https://jsfiddle.net/usjpLjLp/1/)

Comment: @Terminus this solution unfortunately don´t work. Click on the last "picture" it goes out of top screen.

Comment: which "test" is the "last picture"? all 4 look fine to me. **edit** nevermind, just noticed the fiddle isn't pulling in some image that you have going on your actual site.

Comment: Make the result window smaller in height and scroll down. Then the container leave screen.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rakesh commented on the question, this can be done with CSS alone; see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xc2vrghx/1/

You have to use 2 div's.
Outer one with full 100% width/height, absolutely positioned, display set to table & alignments to center & middle - like this:

`display: table;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position:absolute;`

The the inner div (which is your centered container) must have css display set to table-cell, and give center & middle alignments to this container:
  `display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;`

place whatever you want inside this; fiddle example contains additional html inside this middle container to show as example.
CSS display property's **table** & **table-cell** values are playing the magic role here. http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero is a very good article to understand

Comment: but if the parent container is in the site container(cant change my template) does it work too ? Can´t test today .. uploading videos take hours...

Comment: have you tried? may be always better to try first than to ask.

Comment: By the way, it should still work - but may need little more tweaks to the parent/outer containers css. If not, create a fiddle and link us to - with your exact working/non-working code